# Cross-compile Rust for Raspberry Pi 1 Model B

Tags: rust, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross-compile a program written in Rust using the libudev-sys for my Raspberry Pi Model B on my Ubuntu machine.

I have downloaded the appropriate GNU Toolchain (from https://developer.arm.com/downloads/-/gnu-a - "gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf.tar.xz") and added it to my path

I configured cargo for the correct target for my Raspberry Pi: `arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf`.

For a hello world program that doesn't depend on libudev-sys it works fine and runs properly.

When I try and compile with the libudev-sys dependency I get the following error:

```
error: linking with `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc` failed: exit status: 1
  |
  = note: LC_ALL="C" PATH="/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin:/root/down/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin:/root/.cargo/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/usr/lib/rustup/bin" VSLANG="1033" "arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc" "/tmp/rustcZ5Jg16/symbols.o" "/root/rust/target/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/debug/deps/mel_hardware_wallet_driver-ba232661e479b91b.1301xt1j1zx0q0tn.rcgu.o" "/root/rust/target/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/debug/deps/mel_hardware_wallet_driver-ba232661e479b91b.1q7ysdn9z1d55swz.rcgu.o" "/root/rust/target/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/debug/deps/mel_hardware_wallet_driver-ba232661e479b91b.2a5ntvb0ghcwzsiv.rcgu.o" "/root/rust/target/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/debug/deps/mel_hardware_wallet_driver-ba232661e479b91b.2gve3zvwwg1ydgci.rcgu.o" "/root/rust/target/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/debug/deps/mel_hardware_wallet_driver-ba232661e479b91b.2p3eeeq9rc91vjfy.rcgu.o" "/root/rust/target/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/debug/deps/mel_hardware_wallet_driver-ba232661e479b91b.2pl3qotay3ujgdc2.rcgu.o" "/root/rust/target/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/debug/deps/mel_hardware_wallet_driver-ba232661e479b91b.35n0ni1yaz1q15w9.rcgu.o" "/root/rust/target/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/debug/deps/mel_hardware_wallet_driver-ba232661e479b91b.3v4uex5u20x3sd0l.rcgu.o" "/root/rust/target/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/debug/deps/mel_hardware_wallet_driver-ba232661e479b91b.44hcvp051sobvo8m.rcgu.o" "/root/rust/target/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/debug/deps/mel_hardware_wallet_driver-ba232661e479b91b.4iisi6q0m16u9knf.rcgu.o" "/root/rust/target/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/debug/deps/mel_hardware_wallet_driver-ba232661e479b91b.4zmw3k4lfyvsl0u1.rcgu.o" "/root/rust/target/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/debug/deps/mel_hardware_wallet_driver-ba232661e479b91b.c8na9xye41lnp6j.rcgu.o" "/root/rust/target/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/debug/deps/mel_hardware_wallet_driver-ba232661e479b91b.39t9t59sph3lxvr4.rcgu.o" "-Wl,--as-needed" "-L" "/root/rust/target/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/debug/deps" "-L" "/root/rust/target/debug/deps" "-L" "/build/root/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf" "-L" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/lib" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "/root/rust/target/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/debug/deps/libserialport-34252c9024d4d1ea.rlib" "/root/rust/target/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/debug/deps/libnix-59bd89434b707189.rlib" "/root/rust/target/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/debug/deps/liblibudev-824544206b8b27be.rlib" "/root/rust/target/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/debug/deps/liblibudev_sys-1c11ee3ba5521c70.rlib" "/root/rust/target/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/debug/deps/libevdev-f507e89d1e3b0f52.rlib" "/root/rust/target/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/debug/deps/libnix-47738fa0cfa4d4b4.rlib" "/root/rust/target/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/debug/deps/libbitflags-a5e8ac5c5f9cc8b7.rlib" "/root/rust/target/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/debug/deps/libmemoffset-0ef278751d9ccdc6.rlib" "/root/rust/target/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/debug/deps/liblibc-733ecf0f6c247be2.rlib" "/root/rust/target/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/debug/deps/libthiserror-818cd6df075fdef7.rlib" "/root/rust/target/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/debug/deps/libcfg_if-d8da1ad4c72ba790.rlib" "/root/rust/target/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/debug/deps/libbitvec-52cf39f0723ab21a.rlib" "/root/rust/target/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/debug/deps/libwyz-89d4b2128d71c49c.rlib" "/root/rust/target/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/debug/deps/libtap-569ad3a6d9dc42ac.rlib" "/root/rust/target/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/debug/deps/libradium-a40c9d70c0c70768.rlib" "/root/rust/target/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/debug/deps/libfunty-dfc2e14a7a7b9af2.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libstd-909106f6dc92d2a7.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libpanic_unwind-aa5ad9cb79f9ade4.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libobject-c4d383b991a6294c.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libmemchr-ce49aa34720cd1f6.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libaddr2line-1680a3dc826d8828.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libgimli-4d211391121bd32e.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/lib/librustc_demangle-84376a0103fbabe0.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libstd_detect-f29f1c1cd7d564e3.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libhashbrown-1d59a0795c47f9be.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/lib/librustc_std_workspace_alloc-d5f4b0ec90e4835e.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libminiz_oxide-67506894a65a8926.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libadler-3c88d1187df2fbad.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libunwind-5dd79589c23c7355.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libcfg_if-e7e49d34ebaaca9f.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/lib/liblibc-1a353b519d8278cf.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/lib/liballoc-370dc527f1f332d0.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/lib/librustc_std_workspace_core-52e389bbfb6c4a69.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libcore-3a47e0c46aec62a2.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libcompiler_builtins-386e0a3a4e8d4682.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-ludev" "-lgcc_s" "-lutil" "-lrt" "-lpthread" "-lm" "-ldl" "-lc" "-Wl,--eh-frame-hdr" "-Wl,-z,noexecstack" "-L" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/lib" "-o" "/root/rust/target/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/debug/deps/mel_hardware_wallet_driver-ba232661e479b91b" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-pie" "-Wl,-z,relro,-z,now" "-nodefaultlibs"
  = note: /root/down/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8.3.0/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -ludev
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've installed the libudev-dev package for armhf as per this github issue: https://github.com/dcuddeback/libudev-sys/issues/7#issuecomment-786952047 but the linker doesn't seem to be able to find it.

Running `/root/down/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld -ludev --verbose` shows it's looking in the following locations:

```
attempt to open /root/down/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../libc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libudev.so failed
attempt to open /root/down/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../libc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libudev.a failed
attempt to open /root/down/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../libc/usr/local/lib/libudev.so failed
attempt to open /root/down/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../libc/usr/local/lib/libudev.a failed
attempt to open /root/down/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../libc/lib/libudev.so failed
attempt to open /root/down/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../libc/lib/libudev.a failed
attempt to open /root/down/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../libc/usr/lib/libudev.so failed
attempt to open /root/down/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../libc/usr/lib/libudev.a failed
```

But I can't figure out how to change that to point to its actual location.

If I install the 'gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf' package, this error goes away and the crate successfully, however this is for the wrong architecture and segfaults when I try and run it on the Pi.

Comment: Shouldn't the toolchain you downloaded and `gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf` compile for the same target? Anyway, I believe you should be able to get ld it to find the lib with `CARGO_TARGET_ARMV7_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNUEABIHF_RUSTFLAGS=-Clink-arg=-Wl,-L/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf`, but I don't expect that to fix the segfault. (I'll add this as an answer if you can confirm it works.)

Comment: You need to also cross-compile `libudev` for your target, or to get `libudev.so` from your target and copy it to your build machine (`/root/down/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../libc/usr/lib/libudev.so` seems the right place to put it).

Comment: As an aside, are you compiling as `root`? That's usually considered a [bad](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/237660) [idea](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/107192).